# Terminal "Select Default Profile" does not work - no type of terminal is being shown (internal or external)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running VS code

**The issue is Terminal "Select Default Profile" does not work - no type of terminal is being shown (internal or external)**

I have followed steps/guidance from these articles

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch

I have tried

- Reinstalling VS Code
- using `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` setting (which is deprecated but supported)
- specifying a profile in the settings.json file and setting is as default
- Removed any custom terminal settings

```json
    {
        "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
        "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
        "git.suggestSmartCommit": false,
        "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
        "files.exclude": {
            "**/.classpath": true,
            "**/.project": true,
            "**/.settings": true,
            "**/.factorypath": true
        },
    }
```

What am I missing, how can I solve this ?

[image]

VS code version details:

```
Version: 1.61.0 (system setup)
Commit: ee8c7def80afc00dd6e593ef12f37756d8f504ea
Date: 2021-10-07T18:13:09.652Z
Electron: 13.5.1
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following settings file and restarting windows solved the problem

```json
{
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.tslint": true,
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": true,
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
}
```